# is an application build using unity3d for android obfuscated?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Is an application build using unity3d for android obfuscated or in some form proguarded?.
I searched on net and read different views, some say that it is proguarded by default, some say to use a 3rd party code obfuscator to obfuscate the c# or javascript scripts before building for android????

what i want to know is-

what is the best approach when releasing an Android application made by unity3d on google play store, so that the code is obfuscated if someone tries to decompile it.

Comment: Not to bother.  Really, there's nothing you'll be writing there that hasn't been done hundreds of times before.  Its easier to rewrite from scratch than to decompile your code, figure it out with no docs, and grab one particular technique.  You aren't that special and your app isn't that unique.  All you'll do is make debugging harder on yourself.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not. There are plethora of tools that decompile the DLL's into it's respective original assets and source code files.  This is one of the distinct downfalls for using .NET CIL languages, the lack of ability to hide from decompiling. For Android, it may be protected through a few different levels,  but in the end if they wanted to get to your code they could because of .NET runtime. Reflector has been the defacto .NET decompiler for years, and there are plenty of resources on the internet that show how to use it to get compiled code, and allows you to convert to VB, C#, C++ and a few other options.

Like Gabe asserted above however, there's nothing too unique about Unity3D coding. Since it's such an open community and a good active user base giving away code and assets, and selling it, there's nothing top secret that can't be replicated elsewhere. The community for Unity3D is huge, hence the reason for the lack of uniqueness of your code, chances are you've gotten and compiled from other resources and put together. On that platform, it's rare for someone to do something 100% from scratch.

Comment: I get it that the dll can easily be decompiled, but on decompiling the apk of unity I get classes.dex and all the coding that i did in the jars at the android side how can i get the dll from that?, what i want to know is not "whether unity app can be decompiled?" but whether "android apk made by unity be decompiled to get c# code written in mono?"